# How to set photo taken with UIImagePickerController to be viewed/modified into a custom UIViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am currently using the default `UIImagePickerController`, and immediately after a picture is taken, the following default screen is shown:

[image]

My question is, how would I be able to use my own custom `UIViewController` to view the **resultant image** (and therefore bypass this confirmation screen ).
Please note that am *not* interested in using a custom overlay for the `UIImagePicker` with custom camera controls or images from photo gallery, but rather just to skip this screen and assume that the photo taken is what the user would have liked.

Thanks!

Comment: @SVM-RAJESH the suggested duplicate question is about using a **custom** overlay, while this is bypassing the standard UIImagePicker confirmation window. Note that the body of the question noted that I did **not** want to use a custom overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code to maintain your resultant image in same size:

First create `IBOutlet` for `UIImageview`.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        OriginalImage=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
//----------
            imageview.image = image; // additional method
            [self resizeImage];


//---------
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,@selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);

    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }

}



//---- Resize the original image ----------------------
-(void)resizeImage
{

        UIImage *resizeImage = imageview.image;

        float width = 320;
        float height = 320;

        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,320);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,NO,0.0);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

        float widthRatio = resizeImage.size.width / width;
        float heightRatio = resizeImage.size.height / height;
        float divisor = widthRatio > heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;

        width = resizeImage.size.width / divisor;
        height = resizeImage.size.height / divisor;

        rect.size.width  = width;
        rect.size.height = height;

        //indent in case of width or height difference
        float offset = (width - height) / 2;
        if (offset > 0) {
            rect.origin.y = offset;
        }
        else {
            rect.origin.x = -offset;
        }

        [resizeImage drawInRect: rect];

        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imageview.image = smallImage;
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the image picker view controller using an overlay view.

Read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView).

You set up a new view, set it as the camera overlay, tell the image picker to not display its own controls and display the picker.

Inside your the code of your overlay, you call `takePicture` on the image picker view controller to finally take the image when you are ready.

Apple has an example of this here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

For transforms, you can use the `cameraViewTransform` property to set transformations to be used when taking the image.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Expanded on the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have experimented with the custom camera controls and UIImagePickerController, but decided that what I want would be to use the default camera controls, but simply skip the confirmation step shown here.

Comment: @daspianist You cannot remove the confirmation step without adding your own buttons. But implementing two buttons (take photo, cancel) is really not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

After taking the picture, the delegate method would be called:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

In this method, you dismiss the imagePickerController. You have access to the image, so you can play around with the image, possibly display it in a UIImageView. So the code would be something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        //here you have access to the image 
        UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        //Create an instance of a view controller and show the UIImageView or do your stuff there. According to you business logic.
    }
}
```