# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum saves with wrong image size after getting from image context

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to save an image+overlay after taking an image with UIImagePickerController:

```
// Crop a Combined Image from the taken picture - in order to remove the bottom bar
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,
                         0, 
                         [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
                         [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - bottomBar.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,
                                       YES,
                                       0.0f);


// Render both images, the captured one from the camera and the UIImageView that is over that picture
[self.chosenImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[self.coverImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

self.combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now when I check the combinedImage size it is (320,470), which is what I expect.

When I am using the following in order to save to album:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.combinedImage, self, @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), nil);
```

The image appears in album in fullscreen mode and stretched (height is iOS device height). 
The most unexpected thing is that when I define context rect of height less than 440, the image is save correctly to album and not distorted. Once above this height, it forces full screen.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713357/how-to-set-photo-taken-with-uiimagepickercontroller-to-be-viewed-modified-into-a

Comment: "The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen." for the scale factor. Since there shouldn't be a lot of non-retina display nowadays, I'd say it's 2 by default.